# How to select data from data base using sqlj in message broker v8?

Tags: messagebroker, sqlj

Can any one tell me how to to select table from data base using sqlj in java compute node in message broker v8 i have tried every thing in the help content but nothing seems to be working

pls help me as i am new to message broker

Answer (score 0):

Broker doesn't provide any explicit support for SQLJ. You could still call SQLJ programs via a java compute node but by default SQLJ code will not compile in the eclipse based toolkit because you need to run a translation step in order to generate valid Java.

Therefore if you really need to get SQLJ running you would need to separately build and package a jar exposing your SQLJ program as a callable method and then reference this in the classpath of your Java Compute Node's Java project and make a call out from the JCN's evaluate method.

This is pretty long winded and you wont get any support from IBM for the application code you write in this way.

A better approach is to use the provided managed JDBC Type 4 support which is fully supported.